# Vector transform equation explanation

Tags: 3d, mathematics, linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the maths of moving points in a 3d space by making a game written in `C#`.

I'm looking at this [wolfire blog](http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/07/Linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-3) series which explains some basic 3d maths. I've read the first two parts but am stuck on the 3rd. I know it's all really rudimentary stuff but I find Googling for help with equations really hard.

The one I'm struggling with is:

`0*(0.66,0.75) + 2*(-0.75, 0.66) = (-1.5, 1.3)`

How can anything multiplied by 0 not be 0?

So my question is how does this look in code:

`x(a,b) + y(c,d)`

I know it's basic stuff but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *is* zero. 2*0.75 == -1.5 and 2*0.66 == (approximately) 1.3.

Comment: Great, thank you; so it's `(0 * 0.66) + (2 * -0.75) , (0 * 0.75) + (2 * 0.66)` don't know why I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: Exactly. In general, x*(a,b) + y*(c,d) == (x*a + y*c, x*b + y*d). With multiplications and additions you never mix the different components of the vectors.